# Align line shapefile to base shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0

I'm using ArcGIS 10.1 and I have two line shapefiles. I know there is a way to make one shapefile follow the contour of the base shapefile but I can't figure how it is done. How can I make the blue shapefile lines align with the brown base lines? In other words apply the line configuration to the blue shapefile based on proximity?

[image]

Comment: Check out the documentation on ["rubbersheeting"](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m80000000z000000).

Comment: Could you clarify your end goal? Do you want to replace the blue line geometry with the brown line geometry, but keep the blue line attributes and two separate layers? Do you want one file with attributes from both? Is this a few lines that might be manually edited, or a large file you're trying to do all at once? Manually reshaping the line, integrate, a couple of overlay tools, and spatial join are all possible solutions depending on exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Im just trying to replace the geometry of the blue line with the brown one. The shapefile has over 13000 links so it would be hard to do it manually. After they have the same geometry, I can do a spatial join and copy the features that I need.

Comment: They do not need to have the same geometry to do a spatial join - that's pretty much the point of the operation. You can specify method, tolerance, and search radius to control how far apart features can be in order to be joined. Based on your sample image, you simply have one dataset that is higher resolution than the other and a spatial join or possibly an intersect (again, with tolerance specified) would do what you want. Have you tried either?

Comment: I tried a spatial join to the closes link but it messed up some of the link since it join to the closest one.

Answer (score 1):

Try [integrate function](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000002s000000) in ArcGIS.

Comment: How does this tool snap two different layers together?